# Update orders status Google Spreadsheet by checking the status in other Sheet using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm working to get the status for orders to be updated in the master sheet. I have disconnected orders with status in another sheet named "Decommission sheet". While I update the master I need to check the status for these orders by applying the below logic:

- If the order is DECOMMISSIONED && not available in decommission sheet
  then the order is LIVE.
- If the order is available in the decommission sheet then check the
  status if it is DECOMMISSIONED then the order is DECOMMISSIONED.

I have done it in a totally different way but it doesn't work with me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function pathstatus() {
  var MasterSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var MsterSh = MasterSs.getSheetByName('Master Sheet');
  var MasterData = MsterSh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var DecommisstionSh = MasterSs.getSheetByName('Decommisstion');
  var DecommisstionData=DecommisstionSh.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var x=0;x<MasterData.length;x++){   
    var MasterPathName =MasterData[x][2]
    var Masterstatus=MasterData[x][6]
    var MasterStage=MasterData[x][7]
    if(MasterStage == "DECOMMISSIONED"){
      for(var i=0;i<DecommisstionData.length;i++){
        var   DecommisstionPathName = DecommisstionData[i][2]
        var    DecommisstionStatus = DecommisstionData[i][7]
        var   DecommissionedDate = DecommisstionData[i][10]
        if(DecommisstionPathName == MasterPathName && DecommisstionStatus == "COMPLETED") {
          MasterData[x][6]="DECOMMISSIONED"
          MasterData[x][12]=DecommissionedDate
        }else { 
          MasterData[x][6]="LIVE"  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  MsterSh.getRange(2,1,MsterSh.getLastRow(),MsterSh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  MsterSh.getRange(2,1,MasterData.length,MasterData[0].length).setValues(MasterData)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
}
```

In another way

```
function myFunction() {
  var MasterSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
  var MsterSh = MasterSs.getSheetByName('Master Sheet');
  var MasterData = MsterSh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var DecommisstionSh = MasterSs.getSheetByName('Decommisstion');
  var DecommisstionData=DecommisstionSh.getDataRange().getValues();

  MasterData.splice(0,1);
  DecommisstionData.splice(0,1);
  var  Decommisstionpath = [];
  var  Decommisstionstatus = [];

  for(var i=0;i<DecommisstionData.length;i++) {
    Decommisstionpath.push(Number(DecommisstionData[i][2]))
    Decommisstionstatus.push(DecommisstionData[i][7])
  }
  var i=0;
  for(var x=0;x<MasterData.length && MasterData[x][3] != undefined ;x++) {
    var OrderStage = MasterData[x][8]
    if(OrderStage=='DECOMMISSIONED') {
      var PathName = MasterData[x][2]
      var index = Decommisstionpath.indexOf(PathName);
      if(index == -1)
      {MasterData[x][6]="LIVE" } 
      else{
        MasterData[x][6]="Check"
      }
    }
  }
  MsterSh.getRange(2,1,MsterSh.getLastRow(),MsterSh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  MsterSh.getRange(2,1,MasterData.length,MasterData[0].length).setValues(MasterData)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

> Neither function works properly

Comment: You need to re-phrase the question and state more clearly where things are not working for you. What isn't working, are you receiving errors or is the output not the way you want it?

Comment: What isn't working, 
are you receiving errors or is the output not the way you want it?

the code is worked but not reflecting the accurate info.

Comment: if you have a different way to get this data, like in macro I use similar to countifs way to get this data

Comment: If you can, please sanitise and share your sheet so that we can try and understand the issue you are having. Blocks of code without context makes it diffifult to fully understand your issue.

Comment: "Decommission" seems to be spelled incorrectly in the code.  Perhaps that was an error in my edit.  Let me know.

Comment: No, it is not it is the sheet name, i toke it copy and past.

Comment: Also, the code runs properly but not reflect the path status as programmed.

Comment: You may wish to repost your code as I may have inadvertently messed it up with my last edit.  Sorry about that.